# WPF - Trigger event if cursor is at certain position in image

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, datatrigger

I'm trying to trigger an event if the cursor is located in a certain part of an image in WPF. I thought I might try to "draw" an rectangle over the image and use a mousein/out event. I currently don't know how to accomplish this. 
So for example I want to trigger a tooltip if the cursor enters the red rectangle of the image.
[image]

Currently I'm using the `<Image></Image>` Tag in WPF but that does not seem to work out....

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have a control over the Image and set that control's `ToolTip`, you will have the tooltip showing when the cursor is over that.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably utilize, that [`MouseEventArgs.GetPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591423(v=vs.110).aspx) gives me the position relative to the object I hand over as an argument. Furthermore I would try to use the scaling of the image so that this approach is robust to later changing of the image size.
This approach would still give you a bunch of [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in your code, but I don't think that can be avoided.

Here is a quick example showcasing what I mean.

**Final result**

Here is a gif showcasing the result of the approach, notice the

> Yup this is an owl

appearing, when we are over a certain part of the image.

[image: A pretty owl.]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MousePosition.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MousePosition"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" MouseMove="MousePosition">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Feedback"/>
    <Image x:Name="PrettyOwl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="Images/10-dithering-opt.jpg"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="WeAreThere"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MousePosition
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MousePosition(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var scale = PrettyOwl.ActualWidth / PrettyOwl.Source.Width;

            Point p = e.GetPosition(PrettyOwl);

            Feedback.Text = string.Format("GetPosition(Mouse): X = {0}, Y = {1}", p.X, p.Y);

            if (p.X > 100*scale && p.X < 200*scale && p.Y > 100*scale && p.Y < 200*scale)
            {
                WeAreThere.Text = "Yup, this is an owl";
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I might try to "draw" an rectangle over the image and use a mousein/out event. I currently don't know how to accomplish this.

You could put the `Image` and an invisible element (with a background of `Transparent`) inside the same `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="screen.png" />
    <Grid Background="Transparent" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="-40,-40,0,0"
          MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter"
          MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave"/>
</Grid>
```

The portion of the `Image` to be interactive is defined using the `Margin` property of invisible overlay element.